# Add a wrapper around a fieldGroup

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I have create the following [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/miguratuxi/edit?js,output)

Notice how the `fieldGroup` does not display because of the `wrapper` setting.  If you remove/comment out the `wrapper` then the fields properly display.

Ultimately, I am `pushing` objects into this `fieldGroup` from a service call.  I want each of these items within the group to be a `<li>` to the overall `<ul>`.  So I wrapped each individual field with the `<li>` wrapper and I was planning on wrapping the entire fieldGroup with the `<ul>` wrapper.  But Formly doesn't seem to like this approach.

What am I doing wrong?  Or is there a better way of making this list?

Comment: `fieldGroups` aren't allowed to have a `wrapper`.

Comment: Is there a reason why?  Do you have another suggestion on how to do what I am trying?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your trying to do. And I can't remember why field groups can't have wrappers... You could file a feature request...

Comment: @kentcdodds I am trying to create a user list where the list items are retrieved from a service call.

Comment: Also, where do I go to file a feature request?  I would assume on github?  I only see the ability to submit an issue.

Comment: Yes, that's where you'd file a feature request :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately **fieldGroup** doesn't support wrappers, and adding them would mean adding complexity to angular-formly.

Fortunately there's a simple way to accomplish the same results using custom templates:

```
  app.config(function (formlyConfigProvider) {

    // set templates here
    formlyConfigProvider.setType({
      name: 'nested',
      template: '<formly-form model="model[options.key]" fields="options.data.fields"></formly-form>'
    });

    formlyConfigProvider.setWrapper({
      name: 'panel',
      types: ['nested'],
      templateUrl: 'panel.html'
    });

  });
```

See full example: http://angular-formly.com/#/example/other/nested-formly-forms

Comment: I'll take a look at that tomorrow.  Thanks for the suggest but how does adding a simple wrapper around a group of fields add complexity to Formly?  It seems like a good idea to have.  I'm sure there are plenty of cases where adding a wrapper around a fieldGroup would make people lives easier.

Comment: We are having this conversation in two places, lol.  As I stated over on https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/issues/486 ....this is a valid workaround.  However, I personally believe that having to create a new field type and a specialized wrapper for just that field type is far more complex then simply adding the wrapper attribute on the field group itself.

Comment: You're right, a wrapper would be a nice addition for a field group

Answer (score 1):

I could be mistaken, but are you trying to dynamically create a list based on data that is pulled in from a service?

If you are...

Create a custom formly type, that has a template with an ng-repeat on the li, within the ul.  You can then put a controller on the type and pass in your service to iterate on.

Here is an example of what I am thinking:

```
 formlyConfig.setType({

     name: 'myList',
     templateUrl: 'myList.view.html',
     controller: ['ListService', function(ListService) {
         var vm = this;
         ListService.getList().then(function(list) {
             vm.list = list.data
             vm.specific = list.data.specificItems
         } 
      }]
  });



<div type="text/ng-template", id="myList.view.html">

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item for item in vm.list">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item for item in vm.specific">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>`
</div>`
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Daenu, although I was stating my uncertainty, it doesn't mean that I didn't provide an answer to the OP's problem.  Either you didn't read it all the way or you are just being a rep snob.  In regards to angular-formly I believe I have provided a decent answer. In your profile, I don't see much reference to Angular or Formly.  jQuery is hardly either.

Comment: So first of all, angular is a JavaScript framwork, in't it? JS and jQuery aren't my highest reps, but I think I'm able to read the above question & code and understand it. Secondly, I have no idea what a rep snob is and I don't really care about. Thirdly I just wrote the comment. The downvote isn't mine, so there must be at least someone else thinking similar to me. If you're still unhappy with it, just ask someone else about it.

Comment: Fair enough on the down vote being someone else's disapproval.  Were you not the one that deleted my answer?  My point is that you should only give rebuttal, if you have expertise in the area of technology in question.  If I am wrong, then give constructive reasoning, on why I am wrong.

Comment: I can't delete answers. I can only sugest things in my review task. It is 2 much to explain in a comment. But its a matter of quality not technology in the first place. Pls read the help pages and/or ask on meta for further infos

Comment: @SoftEngJason sorry about my lack of response.  It was a crazy weekend.  Thanks for your suggestion but it seems like each item would get wrapped in its own `<ul>` tag, right?  That basically makes each item its own list.  Not exactly what I am looking for but I will take another look at the suggestion.

Comment: Hi Holt! Actually, it would be one <ul> with each item as a <li> rendered inside of it.